# In VS Code this line /** @format */ always appears at the top of my .js files on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm a little confused as to why this line :

```
/** @format */
```

Always appears at the top of my .js files when i save.  I have prettier globally installed as well as the prettier extension installed in vs code, I have it configured to auto format on save as well.  I can't find any info on how to make that line go away or what caused it to start showing up in the first place.

Here is what my settings.json file looks like in vs code:

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,

  "editor.insertSpaces": true,

  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "materialTheme.fixIconsRunning": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Winter is Coming (Dark Blue)",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[jsx]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[tsx]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[prisma]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
  "liveshare.featureSet": "insiders",
  "material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "react",
  "material-icon-theme.files.associations": {},
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
  // "editor.quickSuggestions": null
  "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 500,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "mssql.connections": [
    {
      "server": "{{put-server-name-here}}",
      "database": "{{put-database-name-here}}",
      "user": "{{put-username-here}}",
      "password": "{{put-password-here}}"
    }
  ],
  "window.zoomLevel": -2,
  "cSpell.userWords": [
    "Signup",
    "formik"
  ],
  "prettier.insertPragma": true,
"settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
  "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For anyone running into the same issue, in the settings.json file, I changed this:

```
 "prettier.insertPragma": true,
```

to false

```
 "prettier.insertPragma": false,
```

that resolves the issue.